# Error when executing R script from Command prompt

Tags: r, command, command-prompt, install.packages

I am trying to run R script that works fine when running in Rstudio in command prompt, the reason why is that later I want to run it in Talend ETL tool.

However when I run it in command I obtain the following **error**:

Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted

Any idea how to solve that?

**Note**: I tried to install the packages contrib.url or contriburl but it is not compatible with my version of R.

Thanks.

Comment: `options(repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")`

Comment: Thank you, Roland. But I haven't really understood how to deal with it.

Comment: Can you please provide more elaborated explanation if possible, i am a new user...

Comment: Your script seems to call `install.packages`. You either need to add the command from my comment above to the script or use the `repos` argument of `install.packages`.